# Spring Ehcache not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, ehcache

I have implemented the declarative caching in my Spring MVC using ehcache.
Below is code of Spring config.

```
<cache:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
            <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml" />
        <property name="shared" value="true"/>
    </bean>

<bean id="UserDaoImpl" class="org.kmsg.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>
```

Below is ehcache xml config.

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true"
    monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">
    <diskStore path="c:\\cache" />

    <cache name="findUser"
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
        maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000"
        eternal="false"
        diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
        timeToIdleSeconds="300" timeToLiveSeconds="600"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
        transactionalMode="off">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>

</ehcache>
```

This is adapter class where i want to implement caching:

```
    public class LoginAdapter
    {
        static UserDaoImpl daoimpl =(UserDaoImpl)MainAdapter.context.getBean("UserDaoImpl");

        @Cacheable(value="findUser", key="#userId")
        public UserModel checkLogin1(String userId,String password)
        {
            UserModel   model = daoimpl.selectUserInfo(userId);         

            return model;
        }
}
```

The User Dao code:

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDaoInt
{
        JdbcTemplate jdbc=new JdbcTemplate();

        @Override
        public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)
        {
            jdbc=new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }

        @Override
        public UserModel selectUserInfo(String userId) 
        {
            String sql  =   "SELECT "
                    + "user_id, "
                    + "password, "
                    + "no_of_device, "
                    + "email_id, "
                    + "otp, "
                    + "approved, "
                    + "secret_code, "
                    + "os, "
                    + "version, "
                    + "version_name, "
                    + "mobile_maker, "
                    + "mobile_model "
                    + "FROM user "
                    + "WHERE user_id=?; ";

            System.out.println("calling......");
            return jdbc.queryForObject(sql,new Object[]{userId},new UserMapper());
        }
}
```

And finally this is the service:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login" , method = RequestMethod.POST, headers="Accept=application/json")
    public UserModel checkLogin1(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params)
    {
        String userid   =   params.get("userId");
        String password =   params.get("password");

        return adapter.checkLogin1(userid, password);
    }
```

When i run the project and call the service, everytime the data is called from database and not from cache. However the cache files are created at the specified place(c:\cache) but these files are empty.

I could not find the problem. There is no error in logs. This is my first time of doing caching. Please help me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved the problem.
All the bean configurations and dependency injections were right.

The thing i was missing is that i was using UserDaoImpl rather than UserDaoInt.So i moved the cacheable from LoginAdapter to UserDaoImpl and Used UserDaoInt for defining bean. Because if bean implements some interface then Spring by default will create proxy based on this interface.

[Here is a good article about proxy creation in Spring](https://spring.io/blog/2007/07/19/debunking-myths-proxies-impact-performance/).

However i can use UserDaoImpl if i want but then i have to remove the implementation of UserDaoInt.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for not trying this out on my own first. My thinking is that your @Cacheable key is incorrect.

Please try with `@Cacheable(value="findUser", key="#userId")`.

If this doesn't work, do tell.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I updated the key but it still does not work